# Correct way to write header has multi values in Java web

Tags: java, servlets, http-headers, httpresponse

I am handling HTTP header 'Content-Language' for multi languages. I have 2 ways:

1. WAY1:

   ```
    // setHeader
    response.setHeader("Content-Language", "en, fr"); // Using ',' as seperator
   ```
2. WAY2:

   ```
    // addHeader ----- Not setHeader

    response.addHeader("Content-Language", "en");
    response.addHeader("Content-Language", "fr");
   ```

**My question is**: Are these two ways equivalent? Which one should be used?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use both variants. In both cases a response header `Content-Language: en, fr` will be sent.

Calling `response.addHeader` multiple times for the same header name produces a concatenated version of the header values separated by a `", "`.